# In Javascript or Jquery How to pass external json file as argument to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Am new to jquery.I need to know how to pass external `json` file as a argument to a function.

I know how to pass as a `object` in client side like below.

```
var json = { "key": "value" }
```

Basically i need to call this below function by passing the `json data`.

```
function draw(json) {
 // Code here

  console.log(json);

}
```

In client side `json` means i know to how to pass.

```
draw(json);
```

But my json file is come from server(External Json File)

I tried `jquery.getJson()` method also.But not getting exact solution.I don't know what i did mistake also.

**My `$.getJson` code**

```
draw("$.getJSON("http://localhost/cb/json/Json_30647.json",function(data) {

      return data;   

    }));
```

Please help me to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not return from an asynchronous method!

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: Hi @epascarello.Thanks for reply.Then what is the way to achieve the solution.Please tell any idea.Am new to javascript.

Comment: So use instead: `$.getJSON(url, draw);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not return from an asynchronous method. You are trying to eat the pizza before it it delivered to your house.

Call the function when the call is complete:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/cb/json/Json_30647.json",function(data) {
      draw(data);   
});
```

Comment: HI @epascarello.Got a solution..Thank you so much.

Comment: Love the pizza delivery analogy!